# How to avoid empty folders being copied in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
// current setup:
public
    css
        navigation
            right-sidebar.css
            left-sidebar.css
        main
            header.css
            foot.css
            main.css
        extra
            grid.css
            normalize.css

// trying to achieve:
public
    ...
dist
    css
        navigation
            right-sidebar.css
            left-sidebar.css
        main
            header.css
            footer.css
            main.css
```

I'm trying to avoid the `css/extra` directory from copying to `dist`. I've tried:

```
var src = ['public/css/*', '!public/css/extra/**']

return gulp.src( src )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/css/' ) )
```

This successfully copies all the required folders and their files, but it also copies an empty `extra` directory in dist to give `dist/extra/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `!public/css/extra/**` exclude all the things inside the `extra` directory, but not the directory itself.

To exclude it you need to set your glob pattern to.

```
var src = ['public/css/**/*', '!public/css/extra/']
```

Comment: I retested your solution, and it actually presented another issue - the css files inside `navigation` and `header` didn't end up copying. I found the solution which was:
`['public/css/*/*', '!public/css/extra/**']`

Comment: Yep you're right, have missed that, will edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if something has changed but Apercu's answer didn't work for me.

It also looks like this is somewhat of an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/issues/25).

The option that worked for me looked like this:

```
var src = ['public/css/**/*', '!public/css/{extra,extra/**}']
```